# Jtextfield and keylistener

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I have a jtextfield (jt) where I want as soon as the user types `"e"` for example in it, the word `"Example"` to be written automatically in the jtextfield.

I use the code:

```
KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        jt.setText("Example");
    }
}
```

But this gives `"Examplee"` when e is pressed! Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: as u press key the word 'Example' is set in field but as u didn't consume the event 'e' as added to the text field, use e.consume() to avoid it.

Comment: @Arvind There's no guarantee that your listener will be called first

Comment: @MadProgrammer I agree vid u but OP has asked for d reason n i am sharing my views as to wat would have happened der.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `KeyListener` on text components, there are a rafter of issues (not been notified, mutation exceptions, not been notified when the user pastes something  into the field), instead, you should be using a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

For example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class TextFieldExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TextFieldExample();
    }

    public TextFieldExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
                ((AbstractDocument)field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new ExampleExpandingDocumentFilter());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(field);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ExampleExpandingDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            System.out.println("I" + text);
            super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            if ("e".equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
                text = "example";
            }
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs); 
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can move your `jt.setText("Example");` into the `public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)` of your `KeyListener`

Comment: @user3265784, Don't use a KeyListener!!! The better solution is to use a DocumentFilter as demonstrated by MadProgrammer. This is a newer API and was specifically designed for Swing. KeyListeners are used in old AWT applications because there is no alternative.