# Making calculations without pressing a button

Tags: java, button, listener

I'm making a program that calculates rules of three, but I don't want the calculations to be started when I press button but when the 3 needed values are added. Here's the image of my program and my code:

[image]

```
private void calculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    if (field4.getText().isEmpty()) {
        field4.setText(null);
        field1c = Float.parseFloat(field1.getText());
        field2c = Float.parseFloat(field2.getText());
        field3c = Float.parseFloat(field3.getText());
        float result = (field3c * field2c) / field1c;
        String resultfinal = Float.toString(result);
        field4.setText(resultfinal);
        option = 1;
    } else if (field3.getText().isEmpty()) {
        field1c = Float.parseFloat(field1.getText());
        field2c = Float.parseFloat(field2.getText());
        field4c = Float.parseFloat(field4.getText());
        float result = (field4c * field1c) / field2c;
        String resultfinal = Float.toString(result);
        field3.setText(resultfinal);
        option = 2;
    } else if (field1.getText().isEmpty()) {
        field2c = Float.parseFloat(field2.getText());
        field3c = Float.parseFloat(field3.getText());
        field4c = Float.parseFloat(field4.getText());
        float result = (field3c * field2c) / field4c;
        String resultfinal = Float.toString(result);
        field1.setText(resultfinal);
        option = 3;
    } else if (field2.getText().isEmpty()) {
        field1c = Float.parseFloat(field1.getText());
        field3c = Float.parseFloat(field3.getText());
        field4c = Float.parseFloat(field4.getText());
        float result = (field4c * field1c) / field3c;
        String resultfinal = Float.toString(result);
        field2.setText(resultfinal);
        option = 4;
    }
```

I'm sure that I have to use threads somewhere but I'm not sure how to implement them to my program.

Comment: You can use a `FocusListener` to monitor the changes in the focus changes and make decisions about when a calculation should be made.  You can also attach a `ActionListener` to the fields

Comment: Is this GUI using Swing, AWT, Java-FX, SWT.. ? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score -2):

First asign to every input a KeyListener so they'll know when you've typed, pressed or released a key on them. Everytime you press or type a key on any input, loop through each one and `.getValue()`, if more than one has something different than "", then don't calculate.

First create a class that implements KeyListener so your inputs can use it.

```
class LoopWhenTyped implements KeyListener{

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            for(Component actualComponent : e.getSource().getParent().getComponents){
                 //here's where you're looping
            }
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

In the class that holds your GUI, create an instance of the class we just created.

```
private myKeyListener = new LoopWhenTyped();
```

You must add this listener to every input:

```
field1.addKeyListener(myKeyListener);
field2.addKeyListener(myKeyListener);
field3.addKeyListener(myKeyListener);
field4.addKeyListener(myKeyListener);
```

The e variable references a KeyEvent, when you, so `e.getSource()` returns whatever triggered that event, `getParent()` will return the component that holds it, and `getComponents()` returns all the components it holds.

Of course, you must adapt this general solution to your code structure and research a little bit about this classes if you get lost. I hope it helped.

Comment: No, no no, **never** add a KeyListener to a text component. You can surely add  a FocusListener as suggested by MadProgrammer, a DocumentListener or DocumentFilter to its Document, or even Key Bindings to the component, but never a KeyListener.

Comment: Why not KeyListener?

Comment: See [MadProgrammer's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22955127/522444) for more on this. He is one of the sharpest professional Swing coders around

Comment: Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644309/how-to-fixed-keylistener-on-jtextfield).