# Cancel table selection when escape key pressed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, key, pressed

I'm writing a Swing project in Java and I've recently stumbled upon a problem.

I have a `JTable` full of objects (car park full of cars) and this piece of code changes the position of 2 elements. If no car was selected, set the coordinates of the first car. On next click, if there already was a car selected, set coordinates of another car. Next, swap the elements with each other and erase the coordinates.

Now, I also have to implement a possibility to "cancel" my selection, e.g. after selecting the first car, if a key is pressed, the selection should be erased. Any ideas how could I do it?

```
    jt.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        int y1 = -1;
        int x1 = -1;
        public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            if(x1 == -1 && y1 == -1) {
                y1 = jt.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                x1 = jt.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            } 
            else {
                int y2 = jt.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                int x2 = jt.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());

                Car tmp = (Car)carpark[y1][x1];
                carpark[y1][x1] = carpark[y2][x2];
                carpark[y2][x2] = tmp;

                model.fireTableDataChanged();

                x1 = -1;
                y1 = -1;
                y2 = -1;
                x2 = -1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need a    'class KeyPressed implements KeyListener `
With that you can see the key presses and decide what to do.

Comment: @cliff2310: no, this is a Swing GUI, and KeyListeners should be avoided.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Well I've use them with out a problem, but I yield to your vast knowlege.  Could you point me to some references?

Comment: @cliff2310: first of all the [KeyListener Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) has within it the explicit recommendation to favor Key Bindings. For use with text components, please read [MadProgrammer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954961/jtextfield-and-keylistener), and then up-vote it.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). 
Here is something to get you started:

```
InputMap im = table.getInputMap();
ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "cancel");
am.put("cancel", new CancelAction());
```

`CancelAction` is defined by:

```
class CancelAction extends AbstractAction {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       System.out.println("esc button pressed ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a GUI component, like a JTextField, that can register a KeyListener and program the proper action: see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html).

Something like:

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
tf.addKeyListener(
    new KeyListener() {
            void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // your stuff here
            }
            // other methods must be overriden
    }
);
```

You can register a key listener for other components like buttons and panels as well.

Comment: No, you never should add a KeyListener to a text component. Please search similar questions, especially those answered by MadProgrammer and Camickr, among two of the best Swing coders on this site.

Comment: Instead use DocumentListener or DocumentFilter or Key Bindings.

Comment: I'm a bit outdated with Swing. Anyway, KeyListener works althought there can be better solutions.