# How to validate value from jlabel to jtextfield on java using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have an auto generated numbers that i want the user to input in order to have access to the full function of the program, if the value from the label is the same with the value entered into the textbox, the functions should be enabeled else it should prompt out a JOptionPane that the value entered is not valid, if the value are input *3 it should exit the program.

Comment: Can you show us a snippet with what you have you tried so far?

Comment: JLabel and JTextField both have a `getText(...)` method. Just compare the two values using the `equals(...)` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing offers an `InputVerifier` for input verification. You could implement one and add it the `JTextField`. See [InputVerifier docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html). The textfield will get verified, as soon as another component requests the focus. You could enable/disable your components of choice in this verification-process. If this is not what you want, have a look at the [KeyListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954961/jtextfield-and-keylistener), you could also validate user input within `KeyEvents`.